# os.walk works with non-escaped backslash?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just found a bug in a bit of code I was writing that wasn't actually bugging?

```
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('C:\FOLDER'):
print('The current folder is ' + folderName)
for subfolder in subfolders:
    print('SUBFOLDER OF ' + folderName + ': ' + subfolder)
for filename in filenames:
    print('FILE INSIDE ' + folderName + ': '+ filename)
```

and

```
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('C:\\FOLDER'):
print('The current folder is ' + folderName)
for subfolder in subfolders:
    print('SUBFOLDER OF ' + folderName + ': ' + subfolder)
for filename in filenames:
    print('FILE INSIDE ' + folderName + ': '+ filename)
```

both work in shell and the full code runs fine? Shouldn't that first one be stuffing up because it is feeding it 'C:OLDER'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python ignores unrecognised escape sequences and leaves the original backslash and letter in place.

`\F` is not a valid escape sequence, so your string contains a literal `\` backslash followed by a literal `F`:

```
>>> 'C:\FOLDER'
'C:\\FOLDER'
```

Comment: Note: Relying on this is a bad idea. Use raw strings for Window path literals, e.g. `r'C:\FOLDER'`, so it doesn't barf when some decides the make the folder name lowercase, and suddenly you're trying to walk a folder named `C:<FORMFEEDCHARACTER>older`. Eventually, they may finally deprecate this terrible "feature" (see [Python bug #27364](https://bugs.python.org/issue27364)), and again, using raw strings properly would avoid the deprecation issues.